# Mutually exclusive option groups

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I'm getting familiar with boost's program options utility and I'm wondering is there a way of defining mutually exclusive option groups.
I.e., my program has different flows:

> program --first --opt1 --opt2 ...
>   program --second --opt3 --opt4 ...

So, my options for different flows are mutually exclusive.
Is there a way to define mutually exclusive option groups?

Of course below code will do that:

```cpp
 /* Function used to check that 'opt1' and 'opt2' are not specified
   at the same time. */
void conflicting_options(const variables_map& vm, 
                         const char* opt1, const char* opt2)
{
    if (vm.count(opt1) && !vm[opt1].defaulted() 
        && vm.count(opt2) && !vm[opt2].defaulted())
        throw logic_error(string("Conflicting options '") 
                          + opt1 + "' and '" + opt2 + "'.");
}
int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try {
        // Declare three groups of options.
        options_description first("First flow options");
        first.add_options()
            ("first", "first flow")
            ("opt1", "option 1")
            ("opt2", "option 2")
            ;

        options_description second("Second flow options");
        second.add_options()
            ("second", "second flow")
            ("opt3", "option 3")
            ("opt4", "option 4")
            ;

        // Declare an options description instance which will include
        // all the options
        options_description all("Allowed options");
        all.add(first).add(second);

        variables_map vm;
        store(parse_command_line(ac, av, all), vm);

        conflicting_options(vm, "first", "second");
        conflicting_options(vm, "first", "opt3");
        conflicting_options(vm, "first", "opt4");
        conflicting_options(vm, "second", "opt1");
        conflicting_options(vm, "first", "opt2");
    }
     catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

But I have too many options, so, it will be nice to do checks only for groups.

Thanks in advance!